# can't find how to use Backup and Migrate module

Tags: 7, database, backups

I've installed the module and enabled it.. the brief readme instructs me to go to `mysite.com/admin/content/backup_migrate` but when I go there I just see the same content as `mysite.com/admin/content/` how am I supposed to use this module?

Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: aren't both urls same except for font?

Comment: oh good call.. I forgot to edit my paste

Comment: I assume you checked the permissions page and assigned all of the BAM ones as appropriate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Drupal 7 it is mysite.com/admin/config/system/backup_migrate

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: Ah! Thank you. Now that begs a new question... how was I to find that out on my own? The module page on drupal.org only links to the drupal 6 readme. AM I missing something major

Comment: There is a README.txt in the D7 version that has D7 specific info: http://drupalcode.org/project/backup_migrate.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-2.x:/README.txt

Comment: If there are elements you feel aren't explained well please note them. If you are able to figure them out open a ticket and add them so they can get in the module. If there are things you still don't understand it would also be good to add a ticket: http://drupal.org/project/issues/backup_migrate?version=7.x&component=Documentation

Answer (score 1):

Also, be sure to have the help modules installed and go here for help using the module:

yoursite.com/admin/help/backup_migrate